# Will JOGL work with Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, opengl, jogl

Ever since Mac OS X stopped supporting OpenGL (as of OS 10.9 Mavericks), I haven't been able to find any information regarding whether or not this means that JOGL would have issues working on OS X 10.9+.  JOGL is still listed as cross-platform (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_OpenGL), but I wanted to double-check its status with OS X, if anyone knows this information.

Comment: According to [this table](https://developer.apple.com/opengl/capabilities/), OSX supports OpenGL 4.1 on OSX 10.9. They're probably not going to support OpenGL 4.2-4.5, since they seem to be pushing for their own Mantle API instead.

Comment: @Colonel I think you meant Metal, not Mantle.

Comment: @SurvivalMachine Yea, that's a typo.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Yes, indeed, Apple has stopped supporting OpenGL and moved onto its own proprietary platform (Metal).  However, does this mean that JOGL has stopped being supported on OS X 10.9+?

Comment: They support OpenGL 4.1. They do not support OpenGL 4.2 or any version later. JOGL simply loads OpenGL if available (which it should be).

Comment: JOGL 2.3.2 and the later versions including the next version JOGL 2.4.0 work successfully under OS X, it has been tested on OS X 10.10 and 10.11. I'll consider any false claim according to which JOGL doesn't support OS X as FUD. Reminder: I'm a JogAmp contributor, I'm responsible for engine support: http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Maintainer_and_Contacts#Julien_Gouesse